# How to get the digits in an element's name attribute?

Tags: javascript

I need to get number value from the attribute `name="data[0][post_title]"`   and put it to variable

How can I do it properly?

I started like this, but don't know how to get value of data

```
var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('name');
```

this is the whole html tag

```
<input class="post_title" id="title_0" placeholder="Enter Post Title" name="data[0][post_title]" value="text" type="text">
```

Comment: Can you rephrase the question and add the HTML structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate over `input` elements, with a `name` attribute, use the selector `input[name]`.

In order to retrieve the number in the square brackets of the attribute value, you can match with the expression `/\[(\d+)\]/`. For instance, `name="data[0][post_title]"` would return `0`.

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/d6mc3u7d/).

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input[name].post_title');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function (el) {
    var match = el.name.match(/\[(\d+)\]/),
        number = match !== null ? match[1] : null;

    console.log(number);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I think I understand your question

You're trying to access an attribute and extract a number. In that case you would do the following.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("post_title")[0].getAttribute("name")
.match(/\d+/);
```

Your input element has a a class name of `post_title`. To access this element, you will want to use `getElementsByClassName`. This returns a collection, so to access the specific element, you need to put the index of the element with that class name. In your case, that's zero.

To access attributes, we use the `getAttribute` method. In your case, you'd like to access the `name` property.

To find a number, we will need to search for a regular expression. We can do that with the `match` function. The regex `/\d+/` finds any number.

Try out this example here

```js
var number = document.getElementById("number");

var index = document.getElementsByClassName("post_title")[0].getAttribute("name")
    .match(/\d+/);

number.innerHTML = index;
```

```html
<input class="post_title" id="title_0" placeholder="Enter Post Title" name="data[0][post_title]" value="text" type="text">

<p id="number"></p>
```

Comment: `<name>` is NOT a valid element, something is vague with the question.

Comment: @Richard Hamilton great thank you soo much and one more question, i have like 3 inputs on page and they have different numbers i want alert them just to check they numbers

Comment: I don't understand that question

Comment: @Richard Hamilton, basically i want to loop thru this data[0],and alert this numbers, so basically on page i have different amount with input with different data number, i need to check all numbers on page..